# Angular Footable (ziscloud) shows only 10 results after filtering

Tags: angularjs, footable

I am using footable from Inspinia angular theme to sort a couple of tables that I got. The actual plugin is ziscloud angular footable (found here https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-footable). The table has approx 50 entries which could get more by the time so in that sense pagination is the way to go.
I tried to use pagination but it is not working, plus the first time the table loads all the fields and then it filters the first 10 items.

```
<table class="table table-hover footable toggle-arrow-tiny" data-page-size="8">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="2%"  data-sort-ignore="true"></th>
            <th width="15%" data-sort-initial="true">Publish date</th>
            <th width="15%">Start date</th>
            <th width="20%">Name</th>
            <th width="15%" data-sort-ignore="true">Total bookings</th>
            <th width="23%" data-sort-ignore="true"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in vm.pastEducation">
            <td class="icon">
            <img ng-src="{{ vm.showActivityIcon(item.activity.descriptionText) }}" class="list-icon" alt="{{item.activity.descriptionText}}" title="{{item.activity.descriptionText}}">
            </td>
            <td>{{ item.publishDate == '' ? "" : (item.publishDate | date : "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm") }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.startDate | date : "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm" }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="align-right buttons">
            <button data-ng-click="vm.viewEducation(item.id)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-outline">
               Show
            </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I have included the correct js in the config.js file and I am not loading anything in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all pagination worked from the beginning but it showed up only after I clicked one of the table headers, when it also sorted all the values. So what was left to do was to find out how to trigger the filtering once the table has loaded.
Here is the init function of my controller where it is done

```
 (function initController() {
     return educationService.listMin().then(function(data) {
        vm.ongoingEducation = data.ongoingEducation;
        vm.pastEducation = data.pastEducation;
        $timeout(function () { $('table').trigger('footable_redraw'); }, 0);
     });
  })();
```

This function $timeout(function () { $('table').trigger('footable_redraw'); }, 0); triggers after the dom is loaded and thus successfully triggers filtering. Since I am using controller as one should also declare $timeout in the the beginning of the controller.